# Conversion of number not match with length of datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I refer the following number with datatype `bigInt`.

```
DECLARE @Number Bigint = '269687584'
```

When I convert the datatype to `Varbinary(4)`, it returns `0x10131B20`.

But when I calculate the length of the `Varbinary` data, it returns only 3.
I didn't know exact what wrong.

In SQL Server database, I want to write an query to convert `Bigint` to 
`Varbinary(4)`, but is converted as only as `Varbinary(3)`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
DECLARE @Number BIGINT = '269687584'

SELECT 
    @Number,
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @Number), 
    LEN(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @Number))
```

Comment: The `LEN` function expects a string and returns the length with trailing spaces removed. In this case, last byte of the binary value `0x10131B20` happens to be a space character and not counted. The solution is to use `DATALENGTH`.

Comment: Side note: when initialising a **number**, you **should not** use single quotes - this denotes a **string literal**, so you're really incurring an implicit conversion from a string to your target datatype. Just use this instead to **avoid** that conversion: `DECLARE @Number BIGINT = 269687584` (**no** single quotes needed to initialize a **number**!!)

Comment: Plus: after all **you** defined the variable to be **VAR**binary - variable length - so it'll just use up as many bytes as really needed to store the value - 3 bytes in this case. But there's **nothing wrong** with that! Just convert the `VARBINARY(4)` value back to a `BIGINT` - you'll get the same result as you started with - no data or information is **lost** .....

Answer (score 1):

Use DATALENGTH instead:

```
DECLARE @Number BIGINT ='269687584'
SELECT @Number, CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @Number), DATALENGTH(CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), @Number))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong. You should check lenght using datalength:

```
DECLARE @Number Bigint ='269687584'
SELECT @Number, CAST(@Number AS Varbinary(4)), DATALENGTH(CAST(@Number AS Varbinary(4)))
```